# Initializing Retrofit client in application

Tags: android, singleton, retrofit

Like below?

```
val retro: Retro by lazy {
    PilotApp.retro!!
}

class PilotApp : Application() {

   companion object {
      var retro: Retro? = null
   }

   override fun onCreate() {
      retro = Retro(applicationContext)
      super.onCreate()
   }
}
```

Is this a good way of initialisation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could make a singleton class of your own.

Comment: Can I use singleton initialization in PilotApp? What makes the difference using singleton and DI

Comment: use dagger as already suggested you can have your own singletons. inject the required context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not following the rule of "Inversion of Control" and It is not a good idea.

The reason it is not a good idea is because whenever a class (like a ViewModel, Fragment or Activity or ...) wants to use the `retro`, they have to get the Retro object themselves by calling your first line (`PilotApp.retro`).

The alternative (called Dependency Injection/Inversion of Dependency) is that the Retro object is given to the class (again, the ViewModel or whatever)  when it is initialized.

The reason why this is important is because with the second approach, you can make your classes that use the Retro, testable. You can give them RetroMock or TestRetro that does what you want (for example, mock an api to return an error).

Another note for your example, you don't need to make the retro nullable, you should make your var a `lateinit` and make it non-null.

Comment: What do you mean with "Inversion of Dependency"? Dependency inversion pattern is actually the good approach that you suggested and not the wrong one in the question

Comment: @kingston thanks, I fixed the typo. I meant to say inverting of how you get the dependencies.

Comment: The reason it ..... first line (PilotApp.retro). I am creating retro instance in onCreate() . Does this means it is only intializing only once. Is it correct?